# How does cin.get() works in the next code?(C++)

Tags: c++, cycle

I got this example, but I can't figure out "what is what", please help

```
#include iostream

using namespace std;

void main() {
    char a[10],
         car,
         i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
        if(car = cin.get() != '\n')
            a[i++] = car;
    cout << a << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the [`std::istream::get()` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) will help.

Comment: Read the documentation? Perform some research?

Comment: Try posting your actual code, this doesn't compile

Comment: In questions where you do not understand the output, you should post: (1) the input you supplied, (2) the output you received, (3) the output you expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cin.get() returns a character which is stored in car, and if that character is != newline, then the while loop continues ( of course, as long as i < 10 ).
So basically, your code waits for characters to be introduced in the console and stores them in your array, then displays the whole array.

Comment: And if I typed in, for example, "hello" and then display it, the other 5 sections of the array are displayed too, but that was in the RAM adress already. Am I right?

Comment: No, the unused "sections" of the array are not displayed.

Comment: Then what are those characters that appear after I display my array?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, i must be int, so `a[i++] = car` could work.

Secondly, `a[10]` is not declared globaly, so it is initialized with some random values from the memory; that is why there are some strange symbols after your string. You could avoid this by doing so: `a[i++] = '\0'` after reading the string.

When talking about `cin.get()`, it reads every character on the buffer until it is empty, and after that, it waits for the next input.

Here is your code:

```
char a[10], car;
int i=0;
while (i < 10 && (car = cin.get()) != '\n')
    a[i++] = car;
a[i++] = '\0';
cout << a << endl;

cin.get();
```

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense, `++` works on chars too.  Also your code causes a buffer overflow if 10 characters are input.

Comment: The buffer overflow happens in any case

Comment: @MattMcNabb you are totally right about chars. But it is more genuine to have it int (just saying, i suposed he is a beginner, and having "char i=0" may cause him other problems). Alex C is also right.